# Screen artifact

Tags: windows-10, visual-artifacts

I've looked at several previous questions and answers to this kind of problem but haven't sorted out a fix yet.

I wonder if someone recognizes which program this comes from, then maybe I can fix it from there.

Here's a pic of the artifact (looks like a menu item) on a black background:

[image]

Comment: It might help to include more background in the image for context on location and size.  It isn't clear whether this is a zoom of something tiny, or something filling half the screen, or where it's located in relation to what, which might provide a clue.

Comment: It's only slightly bigger than actual size, 1" from the top of the screen, 4" from the right, which is why i think it's a menu item. The smaller square is translucent. It shows up all the time. I took a screenshot from my desktop which has a black bckgnd, that's the only reason there's a black background. To my eye, that font looks like a font and design MS would use; I just can't quite place the program it's from. (Might not be MS.)